# Align hat on top of bar

Tags: math-mode, accents

How do I align the hat on top of a bar for the letter d? I've tried with other bars like \widebar but it doesn't work.

```
$\hat{\bm{\bar{d}}}$
```

Comment: What about `$\hat{\bm{\overline{d}}}$`?

Comment: That worked, although the bar is a little too wide. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swapping the \bm and the \bar solved the problem

`$\hat{\bar{\bm{d}}}$`

Comment: hm, isn't this @AboAmmar comment? you should ask him first, if he is willing write an answer ...

Answer (score 2):

Should you want everything bold, here's how with `accents`:

```
    \documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{accents}

    \begin{document}

    $\text{\boldmath$ \hat{\bar{d}}$}$

    \end{document}
```

[image]